# Rails 7: How can I remove Turbo completely?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7

I have a Rails 7 application. After some development I see that Turbo (Hotwired) creates too many issues and I don't need it for this application.

Is there any way to remove Turbo completely from an existing Rails app?

What is the recommended way to remove it?

Answer (score 14):

You need to remove `gem "turbo-rails"` from the `Gemfile`, run `bundle install` to update the dependencies.
Also run

```
bin/importmap unpin @hotwired/turbo-rails
bin/importmap unpin @hotwired/stimulus
bin/importmap unpin @hotwired/stimulus-loading
```

and remove `import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"` from `app/javascript/application.js`

Comment: Also remove `"data-turbo-track": "reload"` from your `stylesheet_link_tag` in your `application.html.erb`.

Comment: In order for Jquery to work you also need to remove (or otherwise deal with...but I removed it) the `gem "stimulus-rails"` gem, which works with Turbo.