# ActionController::UnknownFormat After Rails 7 Upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

I have a calculator which users would enter in values, hit submit and without refreshing or re-rendering, the calculated values would display on the page. All worked well until I upgraded from Rails `6.1.4.6` to `7.0.2.2`. Now I receive this error below:

[image]

When I add `format.html` to the `respond_to` block, I get this error:

[image]

When I add `format.html { render :new }` to the `respond_to` block, the page re-renders the `new.html.erb` file but without calculated values (i.e `create.js.erb` file is not running).

Any help would be appreciated.

Here are the files that ran perfectly in Rails 6.

calculator_controller.rb

```rb
def create
  @calculation = calculate_one_option

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end

def new; end
```

new.html.erb

```rb
<%= form_tag calculate_path, method: :post, remote: true do %>
  ... form stuff ...
  <%= submit_tag "Calculate" %>
<% end %>
```

create.js.erb

```js
var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' });

if ("<%= @calculation.error %>".length > 0 ) {
  alert("<%= @calculation.error %>");
  ... js stuff ...
} else {
  ... more js stuff ...
}
```

Comment: `remote: true` relies on Rails UJS which is replaced as a default by Turbo in Rails 7. Rails 7 also has significant changes to the assets pipeline so its very difficult for us to know exactly what you broke during to upgrade process. Without Rails UJS forms will just send normal non-AJAX requests.

Comment: Thanks @max you are correct. My application didn't use Turbo or Stimulus and I don't plan on refactoring everything for those yet. I simply added rails-ujs back and it's working.

Answer (score -1):

In Rails 7, Turbo handles this behavior.

If you want to circumvent this default, you can add

```
Turbo.session.drive = false
```

on a given link or form as an attribute.

Or you can add the same line to a global javascript file, such as the application.js.

```
import { Turbo } from "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
Turbo.session.drive = false
```

See the Turbo guide [here](https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/drive).

Alternatively, if Turbo and Hotwire will not be used at all in this project and you do not want additional gem dependencies, you could remove the Hotwire gem completely. This can be done by following [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70719292/4352317)