# Rails 7 - Devise do not delete user account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-7

My View:

```
<%= link_to 'delete account', user_registration_path, :method => :delete, :class=> 
'delete_account_button', data: {:confirm =>'sure?', disable_with: "deleting..."} %>
```

and I'm redirected to localhost:3000/users ... nothing more. No console errors, logs just show that I was redirected ...

FIRST WORKING EXAMPLE:

Changed `link_to` to `button_to` and it work. Why?

Comment: Can you post the server logs here

Comment: there is no info in logs, just redirect to /users

Comment: do you have any authentication present in app, what controller it is hitting. keep the logs are debug level and try again.

Answer (score 0):

From the rails guides, you need a data turbo method to make it work

```
<%= link_to "Destroy", article_path(@article), data: {
                turbo_method: :delete,
                turbo_confirm: "Are you sure?"
              } %>
```

So update from data key with something similar

```
data: { 'turbo-method': :delete, 'turbo-confirm': 'Are you sure?' }
```

[turbo documentation](https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/drive#redirecting-after-a-form-submission)

Comment: not in my case .. I removed turbo from my app https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70714904/rails-7-how-can-i-remove-turbo-completely

Answer (score 0):

```
button_to
```

Is used to submit a form and send either a POST or DELETE request

```
link_to
```

Is used redirect_to a page through GET requests

Turbo is not necessary here to make the button work. However if you wanted to reload elements on the dom you would need turbo.

Check this tutorial out if you want to learn turbo and Hotwire for Rails 7.

https://www.hotrails.dev/turbo-rails

It helped me out a lot

Comment: not in my case .. I removed turbo from my app

Comment: nice tutorial ... start reading about Turbo ... how it works with google Ads, are they refreshed after click?